# Error Pattern Library python

Tags: python-2.7, nlp

This code from pattern.en import MOOD gives me an error when using the pattern python library example code here is a link to the example.

https://github.com/clips/pattern/blob/master/examples/03-en/07-sentiment.py

I have no idea why it gives an error as in every other line in the file works but that line.
The error is cannot import name MOOD

Comment: Did you install pattern using `pip install pattern`?

Comment: yes as in everything else in the file works but that line

Comment: which line? you need to install python package first to execute that code.

Comment: Line 72. from pattern.en import MOOD